# How to run rgbdslam on ROS fuerte?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

I use ROS fuerte and run:

```
  svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/g2o
  sed 's/depend package="eigen"/rosdep name="eigen"/g' rgbdslam/manifest.xml > rgbdslam/manifest.xml.bak; mv rgbdslam/manifest.xml.bak rgbdslam/manifest.xml
  sed 's/find_package(Eigen)/find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)/g' rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt > rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt.bak; mv rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt.bak rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt
  rosmake rgbdslam
```

When I run rgbdslam, it shows:

```
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$ roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch
  ... logging to /home/sam/.ros/log/dad67c30-ef4c-11e1-9928-20cf30a23845/roslaunch-sam-6267.log
  Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
  Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
  Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
  
  while processing /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch:
  Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch'
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42300/how-to-run-rgbdslam-on-ros-fuerte?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-09-16**:
Duplicate http://answers.ros.org/question/43173/how-to-solve-no-such-file-or-directory-uoptrosfuertestacksopenni_cameralaunchopenni_nodelaunch/

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-21**:
I think not. Because this question also including other problem that which topic should mapping to others or other questions. Is there any list of topic from rgbdslam should map to gazebo kinect and how? Thank you~

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-09-24**:
@sam my bad. you are right. And about the list of topics, could you give an example, I am not sure I understood what you want. I am not an experienced ros-user but I got rgbdslam to work recently.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-25**:
I know rgbdslam should work when I borrow kinect to testing. But now I don't have kinect, I want to use gazebo's kinect to match all topics for rgbdslam. How can I do that? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install the openni_camera package?
If not, install it.

Then it is up to you to
a) start the nodes you need by editing the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file
b) create a /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch file
c) install openni_launch and change the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file by replacing
"/openni_camera/launch/openni_node.launch" by "/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch"

I suppose option c) is by far the most easy, but it also creates a lot of nodes and topics, and there is a lot of information published in /tf(well, that at least is easy to stop, somewhere in the launchfile is a parameter like "use tf" or sth like that.

---

Originally posted by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) with karma: 342 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1